# Change JS Variable based on HTML input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a game in JS and want to have the speed of the ball within able to be changed by a user clicking either a + or - button.

I'm not sure how to do this, here is what I have attempted so far:

```js
var dxoriginal = 6;
var dyoriginal = -6;

document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = dxoriginal;
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
     canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

  .button5 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;

    }

   .button5:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" id="speed">Speed</div>
<br />
<button class="button button5" value="undefined">-</button>
<button class="button button5" value="undefined">+</button>
```

This does display the current speed the game is set to, yet I have no idea how to change it based on the buttons I have created.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hint: onclick=“”

Comment: Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), not `onclick`.

Comment: Using onclick and creating a function in JavaScript to his choosing would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `onclick` attribute to your buttons. In the `onclick` attribute you can define a function to call when the button is clicked. In the example below I have set the `+` button to call the `add()` function, and the `-` button to call the `subtract()` function.

Both functions perform similar operations, one adds and the other subtracts 1 from the value of `dxoriginal`. Once they have computed their output they add the result to the screen by using `.textContent` (this is similar to `.innerHTML` however is strictly for text).

See working example below:

```js
var dxoriginal = 6;
var dyoriginal = -6;
var speedElem = document.getElementById("speed");
function subtract() {
  dxoriginal--; // dxoriginal = dxoriginal - 1
  speedElem.textContent = dxoriginal;
}

function add() {
   dxoriginal++; // dxoriginal = dxoriginal + 1
   speedElem.textContent = dxoriginal;
}


speedElem.textContent = dxoriginal;
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" id="speed">Speed</div>
<br />
<button class="button button5" onclick="subtract()" >-</button>
<button class="button button5" onclick="add()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` attribute to each of the buttons:

```js
var dxoriginal = 6;
var dyoriginal = -6;

function inc() {
  dxoriginal += 1; // change the 1 however you want
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = dxoriginal;
}

function dec() {
  dxoriginal -= 1; // change the 1 however you want
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = dxoriginal;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" id="speed">Speed</div>
<br />
<button class="button button5" value="undefined" onclick="dec()">-</button>
<button class="button button5" value="undefined" onclick="inc()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change that value first you have to get the element and then change the value. You have successfully accessed the element. you have to use on click event handling function.

```js
var speedVar=document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML;

speedVar=dxoriginal;
fuction decreseVal()
{
 dxoriginal=dxoriginal-1;    
 speedVar=dxoriginal-1;
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="decresVal()"class="button button5" value="undefined">-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Mixing HTML and JS

You should take the good habit of [not mixing you HTML and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice). Try not to use this:

```
<button onclick="someFunction">Do something</button>
```

Instead, use this:

```
document.getElementById('some-id').addEventListener('click', someFunction);
```

#### Increasing and decreasing the speed

You can then do this:

```js
var dxoriginal = 6;

document.getElementById('dec-btn').addEventListener('click', decreaseSpeed);
document.getElementById('inc-btn').addEventListener('click', increaseSpeed);
displaySpeed();

function decreaseSpeed() {
  dxoriginal -= 1;
  displaySpeed();
}

function increaseSpeed() {
  dxoriginal += 1;
  displaySpeed();
}

function displaySpeed() {
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = dxoriginal;
}
```

```css
/* Untouched CSS */*{padding:0;margin:0}canvas{background:#eee;display:block;margin:0 auto}.button5{background-color:#fff;color:#000;border:2px solid #555;width:20px;float:left}.button5:hover{background-color:#555;color:#fff}
```

```html
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" id="speed">Speed</div>
<br />
<button class="button button5" id="dec-btn">-</button>
<button class="button button5" id="inc-btn">+</button>
```

### Interactive demo

I got a little carried away and made a demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  ball = {
    radius: 10,
    speed: 2,
    direction: 1,
    x: 10,
    y: 20
  };

animationLoop();

document.getElementById('btn-speed-down').addEventListener('click', speedDown);
document.getElementById('btn-speed-up').addEventListener('click', speedUp);

function speedDown() {
  ball.speed = Math.max(-50, ball.speed - 1);
  document.getElementById('speed').textContent = ball.speed;
}

function speedUp() {
  ball.speed = Math.min(50, ball.speed + 1);
  document.getElementById('speed').textContent = ball.speed;
}

function animationLoop() {
  ball.x += ball.speed * ball.direction;
  if (ball.x >= canvas.width - ball.radius) {
    ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
    ball.direction = -ball.direction;
  } else if(ball.x <= ball.radius){
    ball.x = ball.radius;
    ball.direction = -ball.direction;
  }
  renderCanvas();
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

function renderCanvas() {
  renderBackground();
  renderBall();
}

function renderBackground(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#2e3033";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function renderBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
#canvas { display: block; }
#speed { display: inline-block; min-width: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<p>
  Speed: <span id="speed">2</span>
  <button id="btn-speed-down">-</button>
  <button id="btn-speed-up">+</button>
</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="40"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it that way:

```js
var dxoriginal = 6;
var dyoriginal = -6;
var dx = dxoriginal;

function plus(num){
  dx = dx + num;
}

function minus(num){
  dx = dx - num;
}
setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = dx; }, 100);
```

```html
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" id="speed">Speed</div>
<br />
<button class="button button5" value="undefined" onClick="minus(1)">-</button>
<button class="button button5" value="undefined" onClick="plus(1)">+</button>
```